# What logging information will I get on the Production Server?

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

for the following `PatternLayout`

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %property  - %message%newline%exception" />
</layout>
```

Without mentioning individual properties i am printing all available properties. Below is what i am getting for the corresponding config

```
User=Fred Bloggs, Environment=Production, log4net:Identity=, 
     log4net:UserName=Y, log4net:HostName=X
```

I am developing in localhost. When this goes to production sever (Multithread environment ) will the output will be different or the same i.e `UserName` `HostName` will be of client or server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are getting the information and how you are managing authentication, but if you use `%identity` you will get the user name of the current user using `Principal.Identity.Name`, as opposed to `%username` which gets the `WindowsIdentity`.

Note however that the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) has a caveat about using either of these:

```
WARNING Generating caller information is extremely slow. 
Its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.
```

`log4net:HostName` will return "the name of machine on which the event was originally logged." which will be the production server.